# In Power BI Report Server, web service URL is working, web portal URL is not

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, ssrs

I had to reinstall Power BI Report Server. I reconnected to the underlying Reportserver database. Since I didn't have a backup of the encryption key, I deleted encrypted content. 
At this point if I go to the web portal (http://reportserver/Reports) I get this error: "The service is not available.

Contact your system administrator to resolve the issue. System administrators: The report server can’t connect to its database. Make sure the database is running and accessible. You can also check the report server trace log for details."

However when I go to the web service (http://reportserver/ReportServer), I can browse the report server directory. This information is coming from the underlying database so clearly the report server CAN connect to it's database.

Service restart does not help, neither does restart of the whole server

Comment: I think this is posted on the wrong site.  I would try here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-reportserver

Answer (score 0):

OK I found what was going on. The reason for the reinstall was to roll back from a newer version of Power BI server. Rollback was needed because it didn't play nicely with some other processes on the same server.
In any case... as per MS documentation, upgrade of Power BI server can trigger a (silent, background) update to the ReportServer structure. So after reinstalling the old version of Power BI, I was in fact trying to connect the old version of Power BI to a new version of the ReportServer Database.
Hopefully removing existing (upgraded) ReportServer Database and recreating it from the Config tool of the old version of Power BI Server will do the trick.